# CodeIgniter - AJAX sign up form validation

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, codeigniter, validation

I am building a small web application with CodeIgniter and Bootstrap for my school project and currently I am trying to configure form validation with AJAX. I suspect that the problem is in the controller, but I just can't figure out what it is exactly. Everything is working properly when I am entering valid data, but when there are errors in validation or all the fields are left empty I get redirected to 'http://[::1]/appname/index.php/users/signup' and see the following message:

```
{"title":"Sign up","messages":{"csrf_test_name":"","name":"

The Name field is required.<\/p>","email":"

The Email field is required.<\/p>","password":"

The Create password field is required.<\/p>","password2":""}}
```

Also, please, notice that I **loaded** 'form_validation' library and 'form' helper in 'autoload.php' file. Thanks in advance!

So here is my Sign up form view (without header and footer, they are templated):

```
<div class="container">
<br>
    <div class="text-center">
        <h1 class="display-4">Create Account</h1>
    </div>
<br>
<div class="row justify-content-md-center">

<div class="col-6 card bg-light">
<article class="card-body mx-auto">

<?php echo form_open('users/signup', array('id'=>'signup_form')); ?>
    <div class="form-group input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text"> <i class="fa fa-user"></i> </span>
         </div>
        <input class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Name" type="text">
    </div> <!-- form-group// -->
    <div class="form-group input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text"> <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> </span>
         </div>
        <input class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email" type="email">
    </div> <!-- form-group// -->
    <div class="form-group input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text"> <i class="fa fa-lock"></i> </span>
        </div>
        <input class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Create password" type="password">
    </div> <!-- form-group// -->
    <div class="form-group input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text"> <i class="fa fa-lock"></i> </span>
        </div>
        <input class="form-control" name="password2" placeholder="Repeat password" type="password">
    </div> <!-- form-group// -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block"> Create Account  </button>
    </div> <!-- form-group// -->
    <p class="text-center">Have an account? <a href="login">Log In</a> </p>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
</article>
</div> <!-- card.// -->

</div>
</div>
```

This is AJAX script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var sUrequest;
$("#signup_form").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if(sUrequest){
        sUrequest.abort();
    }
    var inputs=$(this).find("input, select, button, textarea"),
    serializedData=$(this).serialize(),
    postURL=$(this).attr("action");
    inputs.prop("disabled",true);
    sUrequest=$.ajax({
        url:postURL,
        type:"post",
        data:serializedData,
    });
    sUrequest.done(function(response,statusText,jqXHR){
        $.each(response.messages, function(key, value) {
            var element = $('#' + key);

            element.closest('div.form-group input-group')
            .removeClass('has-error')
            .addClass(value.length > 0 ? 'has-error' : 'has-success')
            .find('.text-danger')
            .remove();

            element.after(value);
        });
    });
    sUrequest.fail(function(jqXHR,statusText,thrownError){
        console.log("jq:"+jqXHR+" st:"+statusText+" te:"+thrownError);
    });
    sUrequest.always(function(){
        inputs.prop("disabled",false);
    });
});

</script>
```

Here is the Users controller:

```
<?php
  class Users extends CI_Controller {
    # Register new user
    public function signup() {
      $data['title'] = 'Sign up';

      array('success' => FALSE, 'messages' => array());

      $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<p class="text-danger">', '</p>');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Name', 'required');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|callback_check_email_exists');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Create password', 'required');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('password2', 'Repeat password', 'matches[password]');

      if($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE) {
        // I am not sure if I need this commented part, since AJAX is supposed to perform all the actions without reloading the page.
        // $this->load->view('templates/header');
        // $this->load->view('pages/signup', $data);
        // $this->load->view('templates/footer');
        foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
          $data['messages'][$key] = form_error($key);
        }
      }
      else {
        #Encrypting password
        $hashed_password = password_hash($this->input->post('password'),PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

        $this->user_model->signup($hashed_password);

        #Setting a flash message
        $this->session->set_flashdata('user_registered', 'You were successfully registered! You can now log in.');
        redirect('../home');
      }
      echo json_encode($data);
    }

    # Check if the email is already taken.
    public function check_email_exists($email) {
      $this->form_validation->set_message('check_email_exists', 'There is a user registered with this email');
      if ($this->user_model->check_email_exists($email)) {
        return TRUE;
      } else {
        return FALSE;
      }
    }
  }
```

And this is my Users Model:

```
<?php
  class User_model extends CI_Model {
    # Sign up user
    public function signup($hashed_password) {
      # User data array
      $data = array (
        'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
        'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
        'password' => $hashed_password
      );

      # Insert user in the database
      return $this->db->insert('users', $data);
    }

    # Check if email is already taken
    public function check_email_exists($email) {
      $query = $this->db->get_where('users', array('email' => $email));
      if (empty($query->row_array())) {
        return TRUE;
      } else {
        return FALSE;
      }
    }
  }
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I don't see why that should be happening. I can say you should never render a view as a response unless it is expected, and you should never redirect in ajax request (think of it as an iframe - it won't change the users view port, only the request "view" so to speak). so definitely remove this: `redirect('../home');` and handle your redirect in the success portion of your ajax. this line also doesn't make sense: `array('success' => FALSE, 'messages' => array());` .. copy paste error? also don't forget to `exit()` after `json_encode()` it is recommended although not 100% necessary here.

Comment: also `check_email_exists` and all that functionality can be replaced with `is_unique[users.email]` with a custom error message (form validation library has some examples on how to achieve this). keeps your code simple.

Comment: In the URL you show, `http://[::1]/appname/index.php/users/signup` the `[::1]` part is unnatural. Th is usually seen when `$config['base_url']` is not set. That config item must be set. It must contain the protocol, the full domain name, and end with a slash, e.g. `$config['base_url'] = 'http://example.com/';`

Comment: Thanks for the hint about ```is_unique```!

Comment: @DFriend, you're right, I forgot to configure  ```['base_url']```. Thanks!

Comment: did that solve it?

Comment: Unfortunatelly it didn't. Still getting this message.

Comment: so weird, only seen it happen like this when e.preventDefault() isn't there, but you have it

Comment: hey @JoJo223 i've made an update that i think will work for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: I think the main issue you are having is that you aren't wrapping your jquery in a document ready!

JQUERY:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var sUrequest;
    $("#signup_form").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (sUrequest) {
            sUrequest.abort();
        }
        var inputs = $(this).find("input, select, button, textarea"),
                serializedData = $(this).serialize(),
                postURL = $(this).attr("action");
        inputs.prop("disabled", true);
        sUrequest = $.ajax({
            url: postURL,
            type: "post",
            data: serializedData,
            dataType: 'json'
        });
        sUrequest.done(function (response, statusText, jqXHR) {
            if (response.status == 'error') {
                $.each(response.messages, function (key, value) {
                    var element = $('[name=' + key + ']');
                    element.closest('div.form-group input-group')
                            .removeClass('has-error')
                            .addClass(value.length > 0 ? 'has-error' : 'has-success')
                            .find('.text-danger')
                            .remove();

                    element.after(value);
                });
            } else {
                window.location.href = response.url;
            }
        });
        sUrequest.fail(function (jqXHR, statusText, thrownError) {
            console.log("jq:" + jqXHR + " st:" + statusText + " te:" + thrownError);
        });
        sUrequest.always(function () {
            inputs.prop("disabled", false);
        });
    });
});
```

Note: I've also taken the liberty of fixing your error messages because your fields don't have ids.

PHP:

```
function signup() {
    $data = array();

    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<p class="text-danger">', '</p>');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Name', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|callback_check_email_exists');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Create password', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password2', 'Repeat password', 'matches[password]');

    if (!$this->form_validation->run()) {
        $data['status'] = 'error';
        foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
            $data['messages'][$key] = form_error($key);
        }
    } else {
        $hashed_password = password_hash($this->input->post('password'), PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

        $this->user_model->signup($hashed_password);

        $this->session->set_flashdata('user_registered', 'You were successfully registered! You can now log in.');
        $data['status'] = 'success';
        $data['url'] = base_url() . 'home';
    }
    echo json_encode($data);
    exit;
}
```

Comment: I still get the same message as in OP, with the only difference that instead of ```{"title":"Sign up","messages":{"csrf_test_name":"","name":"``` first line looks like ```{"status":"error","messages":{"csrf_test_name":"","name":"```

Comment: Thank you so much, Alex! Your update worked after I've put the ```<script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>``` line in the header (I guessed there may be issues with the order of loading, since this line was originally in the footer).

Comment: great! jquery is very picky with where it is loaded. if you do it in the footer, just add the scripts that use it after. don't forget to mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

By simply echoing `json_encode($data)` in your controller you are not signaling the client-side part that the response should be considered an XHR response. At this point, what you're doing is the equivalent of loading a view to display data.

We'll use the `output` class (which is automatically loaded) to return the response via Ajax. Change `echo json_encode($data)` for:

```
$this->output
->set_header('HTTP/1.1 200 Ok)
->set_status_header(200)
->set_content_type('application/json')
->set_output(json_encode($data));
```

This is exactly what you need.
Note that you're chaining multiple methods, so no need to terminate each one with `;`... only the last one.

After `->set_output` the controller terminates, so nothing will be executed after that

Comment: that still shouldn't be required no? i used to do it his way with a simple echo and it worked.

Comment: That's the only way I've had success with when using CodeIgniter. Apparently, CI assumes you're intending to output directly to a view/screen if you don't do it this way (although I'm not sure if it's a GET vs POST thing)... With time I grew used to doing it this way and all my XHR interactions respond this way for consistency

Comment: ah i see what you mean, when i used the above method i always wrote: `dataType: 'json'` ... i think that basically told jquery to treat the response as json regardless of the header

Comment: ahhh good point... this is probably related with me not using jQuery but plain old vanilla Javascript on most of my projects :)

Comment: But your answer totally good practice and is what I do now. I was actually going to include it in my answer but felt as though it would add to confusion.